# Run curses terminal application after PAM authentication failure

Tags: ncurses, curses, pam

I have installed `pam_script.so` into my `/lib/security/` folder and created a simple curses application at `/etc/security/onsessionopen` which executes whenever I attempt to login.

The script is executed, this much I know, but the terminal is not altered to show the curses application and instead it just logs out.

How can I force the ncurses application to show?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to force your own TTY and run the terminal application in there.

For more simple echoing, find the `/dev/pts` file descriptor that the current shell is using and direct all commands there.

pam_script.so is immensely useful.

Here's my working curses application with PAM setup which executes after 4 wrong attempts:

https://bitbucket.org/tetris11/custom-pam-curses-warning/